# Reading 100s photodetectors

Tags: arduino, esp32, photodiode, phototransistor, photosensor

I'm trying to measure light intensity at a lot of points in a project. I have about 250 photo detectors (BPX 65). When I had just 1, I tried connecting it to an Arduino board. But I'm not sure, what to use to read all the sensor data? I've read the ESP32 is pretty versatile. I just need their readings and don't really need all of them to measure all at once.

Please help with:

1. How to select components/setup circuit for reading?
2. I previously used PASCO (https://www.pasco.com/products/sensors/light/ps-2176#specs-panel), but it came with its own ADC that I could directly plug into my laptop. Do I need separate components for oversampling?
3. How to design the circuit? Is it as simple as connecting 1 pin to say an ESP 32 and add a resistor and ground the other (https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-fgFBcErUUM0/YSJCcnH4AKI/AAAAAAAABZM/Nj--nR1noJ8RcgkkIZwUVyuSBy2AgZJEQCLcBGAsYHQ/w400-h344/a.jpg)
4. Any links to projects that hook up similar sensors to an Arduino (I'm very basic with Arduino, can manipulate code, read specs, but can't design any electronics that significantly differ from a given design).

Thank you!

Comment: are the light sources grouped closely?

Comment: Which kind of photodetector, or do you get to choose?

Comment: Can I ask how often you need to read the sensors?  How far apart are they?  Where do their samples need to go?

Comment: Light detectors will be very close to each other. Sensor is BPX 65 (https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ams-OSRAM/BPX-65?qs=nTDll3UaDK5aZBDDg1dX0g%3D%3D). Sensors need to be read once (light source is constant). I'd want to fill the outputs into a table on my laptop and plot them in some ways.

Comment: How close is very close? (1cm? 1m?)  Are they in a line, a grid?

Comment: @user319750 Those are pretty nice for what they do. At 18 V reverse bias their depletion+intrinsic region is remarkably similar, one to another, at 60 microns (+/- 3 microns!) And their measured dark current at that voltage bias is about 1/10th what OSRAM says it should be, typically. So they are much better than spec. There is an incomplete guard ring inside them, which implies a non-uniform electric field near the borders. What's your application?

Comment: @jonk, measuring intensity of scattered light

Comment: @user319750 That really doesn't tell me much. There's inelastic (Raman) scattering and elastic scattering (which might be used with Mie to estimate the closeness of small particles to oblate or prolate spheroids versus highly irregular particles, etc.) So are you willing to say more? Or is that to be kept under your hat and we are left as mules ignorantly helping on a problem you set up and that, in the end, may be of less help to your goals than you may now imagine?

Comment: @jonk, thankyou for your questions - they're helping me think through a lot of details that I'd taken for granted. I'm not sure what is the mode that dominates, although my guess is Mie. Light source is an 850nm NIR laser, scattering objects are not isolated so fall across a spectrum, dimension-wise. Is that helpful?

Comment: @user319750 Yes, that helps as much as a couple of added details can help. I now know that there's an 850 nm laser involved (likely semiconductor & distinctly not monochromatic) and that the scattering objects are close enough that there may be coherent phase relations to worry about. But that's still, of course, not nearly enough. This, to me, is a classic example of where someone goes off to design a circuit **long before** they've mastered the sensor/transducer physics. I never consider electronic and/or mechanical/optical design *before* I've gathered as much as possible about the physics.

Comment: @user319750 And even then, there may be unknowns. If there are, I set up smaller scale experimental designs to ferret out details about the unknowns I know about and for which I need more info. And if I have adequately mastered what I think I know about the physics, these smaller scale experiments may also show me unknowns I **don't** know about, but at least have been sensitized to because of the prior physics work I performed. If new unknowns show up, those may also mean additional small scale experiments, then. It goes like that. Only once I know what I need to know, do I move forward.

Comment: @user319750 I have no idea how precisely you can set your photodetectors in a physical matrix. How much variation will there be from one construction to the next one? How much might this single variation impact results? Have you analyzed that? Does it matter? I don't know., But it may. There are variations in each device, as well. The same goes for the laser source, too. And so on. I don't know what you are on about. But given that you probably have coherent phase to deal with, I'd sure want to see your work (lab book) on the topic. The idea of reading them is way at the end of my concerns.

Comment: @user319750 If you haven't already noticed, my life has been spent as a part of teams making instrumentation for commercial and scientific purposes. Usually, providing answers to problems never before solved, so pushing the margins where everything matters and anything that slips through our grasp means years of wasted time and a sad (but educational) failure. I learned long ago to front-end any project by first getting the unknowns into management and clear understanding before proceeding. Otherwise much money and time will be wasted on a painful education.

Comment: @user319750 I may be over-thinking. You have prior experience. But I don't know about that prior experience nor what you are bringing to the table now. All I can do is suggest my concerns and offer the above advice. If you help me understand where you are at then I may change my concerns and agree you are ready to proceed. But from what I see so far, I don't find the kind of detail in your question that I'd expect to find from someone who has already mastered the transducer physics and I have to say that this lack in your question makes me very uncomfortable. So that's why I'm writing as I am.

Comment: Hi @jonk, I understand and respect your passion here. I'm trying to gather if I'd worded the question incorrectly - I'm trying to understand how to collect sensor data when there are over 200 photodetectors instead of just 1. You seem pretty good at EE/ECE and optics, and obviously that's not my area of expertise. I disagree with the notion that every little part of theory needs to be figured out before ever trying anything - perhaps one would have that liberty as a new grad student. To have something work, and understanding why it did, are 2 very different things. I'm interested in both.

Comment: @jonk, I respect the time you're putting into this, and would request and really appreciate if you point me to constructive resources, if you feel there're design steps (from the physics of it), that I need before I can even begin. As a STEM, you'd understand that since I'm moving from a single sensor to 200, I have some good data. From the lack of my discipline in physics, that the optimal physical performance isn't the focus of the project. I am interested in learning the physics, and going back to optimize and trouble shoot, just trying not to as the first step. :)

Comment: @user319750 Thanks for the insights you offered me. It helps and is greatly appreciated. You and I will have to *disagree* about mastering theory first, though. Everything flows out of theory. We cannot even **see** without it. Without the concept of a sphere, we would not be able to notice evidence around us that the Earth curves in the distance (looking at the ocean from a beach, for example.) Our ability to perceive is tied closely to the mental theories we hold in mind. Get that straight. There is always room for experiment. But *after* existing theory has been absorbed first. Best wishes!

Comment: @user319750 Another example which I use to teach the importance of theory in processing experimental data is the small-angle swinging pendulum. Students build some. They are freely given highly simplified theory to understand observation. They may use their heart beat, a stop watch, or dripping water to measure time. They find that all of the pendulums behave within experimental error. Then I provide a break-beam laser timing device. Suddenly, very few fit theory within experimental error. (A reason is the diameter of the hole vs the diameter of the pin used to allow the pendulum to rock.)

Comment: @user319750 We then need better theory in order to understand the residuals we find ***after*** applying existing theory. If we fail to imagine such new ideas to apply, then we are left with treating the residuals as *unknown* until such theory is uncovered. When it is, we can apply it to refine our prediction from theory and we will then find a new set of (smaller) residuals. And so it goes. But theory always comes first. Observation cannot be understood without first applying what we do know from theory.

Comment: @user319750 In your specific case, where I have interpreted your writing as suggestive that coherent phase relations may be important, I almost cannot imagine moving forward without applying sensitivity theory to various design and implementation details that might impact results. (Obviously, I may miss things in this process. But the process itself remains vital so that I can uncover my failures when observation arrives.) I may early on find one or two key issues that are far more important than the rest and this realization then helps shape how much and where time and money is spent.

Comment: @user319750 You are where you are. And I'm fine with that. We all learn as we may. And thank you for at least entertaining my questions. There are too few who do and you have earned my sincere respect given that fact alone. I'm sure you will do fine on your own. And you have my very best wishes! Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 2):

For that many you'd probably want to put them in a matrix. An 8 x 8 matrix would do 256 sensors.

The basic idea is you arrange the photodiodes in 8 rows of 8 columns, then use a microprocessor to select the column and row of whichever one you want to read. This way you only need 16 I/O lines to address them.

Here's a diagram of a basic 8 x 8 diode arrray.

[image]

The difficult part is going to be designing the multiplexing circuit to switch each photodiode so it can be read by the ADC in the microprocessor. You would probably need to use transistors or MOSFETS to ground the selected row and an 8 channel analog multiplexer to switch the selected column into the ADC. An example of a multiplexer is the [CD74HC4051](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4051-q1.pdf) which may or may not suit your needs. You may also need amplifiers for the photodiodes. It's not a simple project, but it's better than trying to find a micro with 250 analog inputs.